# How to interact with an element with Selenium when I don't have it's id?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to send a message to [this webpage][1] with Python.

It is to say to do the following but with Python:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

That's why I tried the following script with Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

api_location = 'http://iphoneapp.spareroom.co.uk'
api_search_endpoint = 'flatshares'
api_details_endpoint = 'flatshares'

location = 'http://www.spareroom.co.uk'
details_endpoint = 'flatshare/flatshare_detail.pl?flatshare_id='

text = "Hello ! I am interested in your offer"
email = "myemail"
password = "mypassword"



def contact_room(room_id):
    url = '{location}/{endpoint}/{id}?format=json'.format(location=api_location, endpoint=details_endpoint, id=room_id)
    print(url)
    driver_path = 'C:\Program Files\chromedriver'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = driver_path )  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
    # Go to your page url
    driver.get(url)
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"li.emailadvertiser > .button.button--wide"))).click()

    # writting the text
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "message"))
    )  # Wait until the `text` element appear (up to 5 seconds)
    driver.find_element_by_id("message").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id('message').send_keys(text)

    # writing my email, but I don't have the id of the element
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.formlabel > .button.login_email"))
    )  # Wait until the `email` element appear (up to 5 seconds)
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.formlabel > .button.login_email")).sendKeys(email);

contact_room(4121595)
```

Everything runs well until trying to reach the email field. Indeed, I can't get its id as it seems there is none. So I tried `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.formlabel > .button.login_email"))` but it gives me back :

```
(C:\Users\antoi\Anaconda2) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\roomfinder>python test_message.py
http://iphoneapp.spareroom.co.uk/flatshare/flatshare_detail.pl?flatshare_id=/4121595?format=json

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56296/devtools/browser/a1cf1399-78ea-4411-aa0a-53bf5352c359
[16004:3276:1114/024915.358:ERROR:wmi_refresher.cc(129)] Unable to add the Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk enum.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_message.py", line 42, in <module>
    contact_room(4121595)
  File "test_message.py", line 37, in contact_room
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.formlabel > .button.login_email"))
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: You can find elements by means other than by ID. There's `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='login_email']")`. See https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath: XPath is the language used for locating nodes in an XML document. As HTML can be an implementation of XML (XHTML), Selenium users can leverage this powerful language to target elements in their web applications. XPath extends beyond (as well as supporting) the simple methods of locating by id or name attributes, and ...

Comment: Can you construct and share the url?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you find the wrong element of email field.

I can't find '.button.login_email' on the page.

Remember that you only can sendKeys to **input** element.

Try to use below css selector:

```
input[name="login_email"]
```

You can write css selector like this:

> tag[attribute="xxx"]

[image]

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#selectors